# keep getting typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' in python

Tags: python, debugging

Taking a beginning Python class and was asked to debug a small program. Have all of it done except this one part

```
a = 2             # Declare a variable with a value, 2
b = 19             # Declare a variable with a value, 19               
c = a + (".") + b       # Concatanate strings, a, ".", and b 
print (type(c))     # print c's type
print (c)           # print c
```

Expected output

```
class<str>
2.19
```

can't figure out this decimal point I know it has something to do with that.

Comment: ```c = str(a) + (".") + str(b)```. You can not add integer to a string as the error says. Convert the ints to strs.

Comment: Adding to saradartur's, if you've python3.6+ try using `f-strings` -> `f'{a}.{b}'`

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are of type int. You have to change them to strings to do the concatenation:

```
a = 2             
b = 19             
c = str(a) + "." + str(b)       
print (type(c))    
print (c)
```